# Convert model data before AJAX response in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I fetch some user data for a view via AJAX:

```
public function adminFetchUserDXData($id) {
    $this->ajax_response(array('data'=>$this->UserDXEntry->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('user_id' => $id)
    ))));
}
```

I use CakePHP 2 and want to convert a timestamp field from several fetched entries to a formatted date before sending it.

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is quite an open question.

Comment: Unfortunately this was a dead end for me, so far...

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow is to assist you in problems you're having, not write code for you. It's important to include HOW you ended up at a "dead end" and any debug information you've found.  This shows us that you've at least tried yourself and provides valuable information for us to assist with.